# Invalid Postback or Callback argument when insert data to database asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have problem when inserting data into a SQL Server database from asp.net.

This is my code:

```
conn.Open()

cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ERDETAIL(ERNO, DESCRIPTION) VALUES('" + txERNo.Text + "','" + txDescription.Text + "')", conn)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

when I run that query I get this error :

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Please help

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: how are you calling this piece of code. share your HTML markup and the complete event/method. Showing the piece of code doesn't help in any case.

Comment: Certain posts will generate errors based on the data that is contained within the post, if it looks like Sql Injection, it'll be rejected.  This is by design.  @marc_s is spot on, you need to change your Sql to a parametrized query.  Without any html/asp markup this is all that can be assumed.